# Add a number of days to a date/datetime (Pandas/Numpy)

Tags: python, pandas, date, numpy, datetime

In Pandas, I would like to add a number of days to a date/datetime (two columns).

Example:

`dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range("20180101 00:00", "20180104 00:00"))`

```
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-02
2   2018-01-03
3   2018-01-04
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

`days = pd.Series(np.arange(4)).astype('float')`

```
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
dtype: float64
```

What I have tried (and the associated error I get):

```
dates + days
```

> TypeError: cannot operate on a series without a rhs of a series/ndarray of type datetime64[ns] or a timedelta

```
dates + days.astype('int')
```

> TypeError: incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [__add__]

```
dates + pd.DateOffset(days=days)
```

> TypeError: DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation +

```
dates + np.timedelta64(days.values)
```

> ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta

```
dates + pd.offsets.Day(days)
```

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to

```
dates + pd.datetools.timedelta(days=days)
```

> TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series

Answer (score 5):

At last I have found two methods!:

```
dates + pd.to_timedelta(days, unit='D')
```

or

```
dates + pd.TimedeltaIndex(days, unit='D')
```

Which both produce:

```
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-03
2   2018-01-05
3   2018-01-07
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

(It took ages to find the relevant documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#to-timedelta)